# Assassin Program Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have to create a program where I have a list of peoples names and have to assign them by random who will be stalking who and who will be killing who.

I have my program here but I am having some errors. The list of who killed who will and everything after that will not appear in the output and I am wondering if I could get some help

Here is my program so far:

AssassinMain.java:

```js
package Assassin;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class AssassinMain {
 
 public static final String INPUT_FILENAME = "names.txt";
 

 public static final boolean RANDOM = false;
 
 /**
  * If not random, use this value to guide the sequence of numbers
  * that will be generated by the Random object.
  */
 public static final int SEED = 42;


 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
     
     File inputFile = new File(INPUT_FILENAME);
     if (!inputFile.canRead()) {
         System.out.println("Required input file not found; exiting.\n" + inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
         System.exit(1);
     }
     Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
     
     Set<String> names = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
     while (input.hasNextLine()) {
         String name = input.nextLine().trim().intern();
         if (name.length() > 0) {
             names.add(name);
         }
     }
     ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(names);
     Random rand = (RANDOM) ? new Random() : new Random(SEED);
     Collections.shuffle(nameList, rand);
     
     AssassinManager manager = new AssassinManager(nameList);

    
     Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
     while (!manager.isGameOver()) {
         oneKill(console, manager);
     }

     // report who won
     System.out.println("Game was won by " + manager.winner());
     System.out.println("Final graveyard is as follows:");
     manager.printGraveyard();
 }

 
 public static void oneKill(Scanner console, AssassinManager manager) {
     
     System.out.println("Current kill ring:");
     manager.printKillRing();
     System.out.println("Current graveyard:");
     manager.printGraveyard();
     
     
     System.out.println();
     System.out.print("next victim? ");
     String name = console.nextLine().trim();
     
     
     if (manager.graveyardContains(name)) {
         System.out.println(name + " is already dead.");
     } else if (!manager.killRingContains(name)) {
         System.out.println("Unknown person.");
     } else {
         manager.kill(name);
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
}
```

AssassinNode.java:

```js
package Assassin;

//CSE 143, Homework 4: Assassin
//
//Instructor-provided support class.  You should not modify this code!

/**
* Each AssassinNode object represents a single node in a linked list
* for a game of Assassin.
*/
public class AssassinNode {
 
public String name;        // this person's name
 public String killer;      // name of who killed this person (null if alive)
 public AssassinNode next;  // next node in the list (null if none)

 
 /**
  * Constructs a new node to store the given name and no next node.
  */
 public AssassinNode(String name) {
     this(name, null);
 }

 /**
  * Constructs a new node to store the given name and a reference
  * to the given next node.
  */
 public AssassinNode(String name, AssassinNode next) {
     this.name = name;
     this.killer = null;
     this.next = next;
 }
}
```

AssassinManager.java:

```js
package Assassin;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * AssassinManager that keeps track of who is stalking whom and the history
 * of who killed whom by maintaining two linked lists, a list of players who
 * are currently alive in the "kill ring" and a list of players who are
 * currently dead in the "graveyard".
 *
 */
public class AssassinManager 
{

    /**
     * killRingFront field: reference to the front node of the kill ring
     */
    private AssassinNode killRingFront;

    /**
     * graveyardFront field: reference to the front node of the graveyard (null if empty)
     */
    private AssassinNode graveyardFront;

    /**
     * Initialize a new assassin manager over the given list of people.
     * @param names
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the list is null or has a size of 0
     */
    public AssassinManager(ArrayList<String> names) 
    {
        // You receive a list of names (as a parameter).
        // Take the names and build up the kill ring of linked nodes that
        // contains the names in the same order as you received them in
        // the ArrayList. You may assume that the names are non-empty, non-null
        // strings and that there are no duplicates.
        // Note: you receive a list of names as strings. You need to create a new
        // AssassinNode object for each player and put their name into the node
        // and connect the nodes together into a list that killRingFront references.

        // your code goes here
     int temp = 0;
     
     while( temp < names.size())
     {
     if( killRingFront == null)
     {
      
      killRingFront = new AssassinNode(names.get(temp)); 
      
      
      
     }
     else
     {
      AssassinNode current = killRingFront;
      while( current.next != null)
      {
       current = current.next;
      }
      current.next = new AssassinNode( names.get(temp));
       
      
     }
     temp++;
     }
     
    }

    /**
     * Prints the names of the people in the kill ring, one per line, indented
     * by two spaces, as "name is stalking name". The behavior is unspecified if
     * the game is over.
     */
    public void printKillRing() 
    {
        // your code goes here
     AssassinNode current = killRingFront;
     while( current.next != null)
     {
      System.out.println("  " +  current.name + " is stalking " + current.next.name ); 
      current = current.next;
     }
     
     
    }

    /**
     * Prints the names of the people in the graveyard, one per line, with each
     * line indented by two spaces, with output of the form "name was killed by
     * name". It should print the names in the opposite of the order in which
     * they were killed (most recently killed first, then next more recently
     * killed, and so on). It should produce no output if the graveyard is empty.
     */
    public void printGraveyard() 
    {
        // your code goes here
     AssassinNode current = graveyardFront;
     
  
     if (graveyardFront == null)
        {
          return;
        }
        
     for(current = graveyardFront ; current.next != null; current = current.next)
     {
      
      System.out.println("  " + current.name + " was killed by " + current.killer );
      
      
     }
     System.out.println(current.name); 
         
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if <code>name</code> is in the current kill ring.
     * @param name name to check
     * @return true if the <code>name</code> is in the kill ring and false otherwise
     */
    public boolean killRingContains(String name) 
    {
       
     AssassinNode current;
     for(current = killRingFront ; current.next != null; current = current.next)
     {
      if( current.name.equals(name))
     {
      return true;
     }
     }
     return false; 
     
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if <code>name</code> is in the current graveyard.
     * @param name name to check
     * @return true if the <code>name</code> is in the graveyard and false otherwise
     */
    public boolean graveyardContains(String name) 
    {
     
     AssassinNode current = graveyardFront;
     
     if( graveyardFront == null)
     {
      return false;
     }
     for(current = graveyardFront ; current.next != null ; current = current.next)
     {
      if( current.name.equals(name))
      {
       return true;
      }
     }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if the game is over (if the kill ring has only one player
     * remaining).
     * @return true if the game is over and false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isGameOver() 
    {
     
     if(killRingFront.next == null)
     {
      return true;
     }
     else
     {
      return false; 
     }
       
    }

    /**
     * Obtains the name of the winner of the game.
     * @return name of the winner of the game or <code>null</code> if the game
     *         is not over
     */
    public String winner() 
    {
     String winner;
     AssassinNode current;
     
     if( isGameOver())
     {
      for(current = killRingFront ; current.next != null; current = current.next)
         {
       winner = current.name;
       return winner;
         }
     }
        return null; // delete this line and replace it with your code for this method
    }

    /**
     * Transfers a player from the kill ring to the front of the graveyard. This
     * operation does not change the relative order of the kill ring. Case is
     * ignored in comparing names.
     * @param name the name of the player to be transferred from the kill ring
     *             to the graveyard
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the game is over
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the given name is not part of the kill ring
     */
    public void kill(String name) 
    {
        // your code goes here
     AssassinNode current, previous;
     for( current = killRingFront, previous= null; current != null && !current.name.equals(name); current = current.next)
     {
      previous = current;
      
     }
     
     if( previous == null)
     {
      AssassinNode temp = killRingFront;
      killRingFront = killRingFront.next;

      while( previous.next != null)
      {
       previous= previous.next;
      }
//      previous.next = current.next;
//      current.killer = previous.name;
//      current.next = graveyardFront;
      addtoGraveyard(temp);
     }
     else
     { 
      AssassinNode temp = killRingFront;
      previous.next = current.next;
      current.killer = previous.name;
      current.next = graveyardFront;
      
      addtoGraveyard(temp);
      
     }
     
     
     
     
    }
    
    private void addtoGraveyard(AssassinNode dead)
    {
      
    }

}
```

```js
Don Knuth
Alan Turing
Ada Lovelace
Charles Babbage
John von Neumann
Grace Hopper
Bill Gates
Tim Berners-Lee
Alan Kay
Linus Torvalds
Alonzo Church
```

Now I know this is alot of programming But My problem is I cant get my list of people who were killed to come up in the output, the list is suppose to grow and grow as each person choosen as the next victim is suppose to die. My professor instruct me to create a private void addtograveyard to help. I am not 100% sure what to put here exactly to make it work?  Do I right the same thing as from the printgraveyard method? Also when I go over the list I need to have the very last person in the list to  stalk the first person on the list and to kill the first person on the list . Can you guys help me on how to make that work in my program and where will I have it typed at.I really do need some help here guys this is all I need to complete my program. Thanks guys!

Comment: If you're seeing compilation errors or runtime exceptions, please post the full error / exception messages with your question including an indication of which lines are causing them.

Comment: Im not getting any errors.. the graveyard list wont come up in the output

Comment: and I just want to know how to have the first and last names in the text file to stalk and kill like the other names in the file

Answer (score 0):

The `graveyardFront` denotes the head of a linked list full of "dead assassins".  When you add to graveyard, it's essentially like adding to the linked list.

```
private void addToGraveYard(AssassinNode node) {
    if (graveyardFront == null) {
        graveyardFront = node;
    }
    else {
        node.next = graveyardFront;
        graveyardFront = node;}
    }
}
```

Comment: So I just out that in and this was the output:

Comment: Current graveyard:
  Linus Torvalds was killed by null,
  Don Knuth was killed by null,
  Alan Turing was killed by null,
  Tim Berners-Lee was killed by null,
  Alan Kay was killed by null,
  Charles Babbage was killed by null,
  John von Neumann was killed by null,
  Ada Lovelace was killed by null,
  Alonzo Church was killed by null,
Grace Hopper

next victim?

Comment: This is a good place to point out that, since you now have output, you can debug your code without using the debugger.  A good start would be to say to yourself, "Okay, when my assassins die I'm not actually setting their killers.  Or, if I do set it in code segment X, there exists a code segment Y that is preventing X from being executed."  Now you rinse and repeat this method of debugging and fixing code until your program works.  Good luck!

Comment: ok so After running the debugger I found that:  if (graveyardFront == null)
        {
          return;
        }

Comment: it saids null for the graveyardFront in the print graveyard method